# React Routes Did not response and cant route

Tags: react-router

in App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Contact from './pages/Contact'
import Error404 from './pages/Error404'

export default function App() {
return (
<>

<h1>This is Home</h1>

<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>

<Route to="/" element={ <App />}  />
<Route to="/Contact" element={Contact}  />
<Route to="*" element={ <Error404 />}  />

</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>

</>
)
}
```

I change mylink to http://localhost:3000/Contact and any others but the page didnt change